# How to Rollback previous transaction in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, rollback, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have run a command accidentally in Redshift, which is updating a few rows (around 100) of an existing table. Now, I need to remove the effect of that command, so I need to rollback this previous command. Also, I am using SQL Workbench/J in which I have selected the option of "autocommit".
Is there any way to rollback my faulty transaction?
Any suggestion or help would be appreciat

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to undo the change after the data has been committed.

If you have **automatic snapshots** activated for the database, you could [Restore a table from a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html#working-with-snapshot-restore-table-from-snapshot) to retrieve the data from a time prior to your change.